# Rmarkdown addin for creating new post not working

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

Today I wanted to create a new post for my website (built using blogdown), but the New Post addin doesn't seem to work.
When I select "New Post" or run

> blogdown:::new_post_addin()

I get an error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Cannot parse the YAML metadata in 'content/photo.md': Scanner error: while scanning an alias at line 3, column 1 did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character at line 3, column 2

2: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Cannot parse the YAML metadata in 'content/research.md': Scanner error: while scanning an alias at line 4, column 1 did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character at line 4, column 2
```

I am not sure what the additional warnings are about, but I want to focus on the main error. Here are details returned by traceback():

```
> traceback()
10: lapply(meta, `[[`, i)
9: unlist(lapply(meta, `[[`, i))
8: blogdown:::collect_yaml()
7: eval(exprs[i], envir)
6: eval(exprs[i], envir)
5: sys.source(pkg_file("scripts", file), envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()), 
       keep.source = FALSE)
4: xfun::in_dir(site_root(), expr)
3: in_root(sys.source(pkg_file("scripts", file), envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()), 
       keep.source = FALSE))
2: source_addin("new_post.R")
1: blogdown:::new_post_addin()
```

Interestingly, when I run this command:

> blogdown::new_post(title, ext = '.md')

it works fine and I can create a new post. I updated both blogdown and hugo but to no avail. Could someone help me understand what this error is about? Other addins (such as Insert Image) work fine.

As requested, the githup repo is https://github.com/msmielak/msmielak.github.io and the dput() output is below:

```
>dput(blogdown:::scan_yaml())
list(`content/about.md` = "<img align=\"right\" src=\"/./about_files/rsz_screenshot_2020-12-28_une_home.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"100px\"/>\n\n**2014-**\nPhD candidate at the School of Environmental and Rural Sciences University of New England in Armidale, Australia.", 
    `content/code.md` = NULL, `content/contact.md` = NULL, `content/photo.md` = NULL, 
    `content/post/2021-03-29-extracting-date-and-time-from-photo-using-ocr-engine-tesseract/index.md` = list(
        title = "Extracting date and time from camera trap photos using R and tesseract", 
        author = "", date = "2021-03-29", slug = list(), categories = c("code", 
        "R"), tags = c("R", "code", "camera trap", "OCR"), description = "", 
        featured = "", featuredalt = "", featuredpath = "", linktitle = ""), 
    `content/research.md` = NULL, `content/technology.md` = NULL)

Warning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Cannot parse the YAML metadata in 'content/code.md': Parser error: did not find expected <document start> at line 3, column 67
2: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Cannot parse the YAML metadata in 'content/photo.md': Scanner error: while scanning an alias at line 3, column 1 did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character at line 3, column 2

3: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Cannot parse the YAML metadata in 'content/research.md': Scanner error: while scanning an alias at line 4, column 1 did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character at line 4, column 2
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(blogdown:::scan_yaml())` in your post? Or provide a reproducible example such as a Github repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The YAML metadata of the file `content/about.md` seems to be invalid. Normally YAML metadata should be of the form:

```yaml
---
tag1: value1
tag2: value2
---
```

---

Update: with the dev version of **blogdown** (>= v1.2.4), the error will no longer occur. What's more, `blogdown::check_site()` can detect this problem and suggest users fix the problematic YAML metadata.

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I was also wondering why it looks different but I cannot figure out where it comes from and, interestingly, it worked.
Anyway, I fixed that and now I am getting:

Error in find_config() : 
  Cannot find the configuration file config.toml | config.yaml of the website

Despite there clearly being a config.toml file in the main directory.

Comment: For `Error in find_config()`, you need to make sure the config file is under your working directory (check `getwd()`, and `setwd()` accordingly), or under a parent directory of your working directory. If you are using an RStudio project, normally you won't run into this problem or need to `setwd()`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the first thing I checked and working directory is correct and when running list.files() first file listed is config.toml, so very weird indeed.

Comment: Ok, I restarted my computer, reopened the RStudio project and now it works fine, so thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know how you ran into a problematic working directory, but I'm glad to hear that reopening the project solved the problem!

Comment: BTW, I also pushed two fixes in the dev version of blogdown that might help you in the future (see my updated answer).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for your help.