# Rmakdown serious problem with strange warning and error message in out of bound I never encounterd

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Oh my god, the problem nearly drive me crazy.

I even used simplest method to create a markdownfile with default format through clicking `Knit` button, and before it , I chose output format in `knit to PDF`. whatever I tried `knit to HTML` or `Knit to HTML`, it was always giving warning message and didn't output anything. The warning message is below:

```
processing file: _main.Rmd
output file: _main.knit.md


Output created: _main.html

Output created: D:/R-project/me/0000-MainCottonAkesu/NewProcedure2021/Rmarkdown/_main.html
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  Could not force captions - error occurred: 'Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'xmlParent': subscript out of bounds
```

I tried creating new projects but didn't work. I nearly can't resolve it. Please help me.
Sincerely thanks to you.

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czYmp.png]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rmarkdown addin for creating new post not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857582/rmarkdown-addin-for-creating-new-post-not-working)

Comment: try to update your rmarkdown